# How do I disable the touchpad while typing on Macbook?

Tags: touchpad, macbook

I have a Macbook Pro 5.5 and I can't disable the touchpad while I'm typing. I have tried downloading `gsynaptics` manager or something like that, but still no dice!

This is driving me up the wall, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type the following command:

syndaemon -k -i 2 -d

Type some text in Gedit or LibreOffice to see if it works ok. It should completely disable your touchpad while typing. I'm using it myself on my Macbook Pro 5,3.

Now, you want it to start automatically when you log in: launch your start up utility (in french it's called "Applications au démarrage"), create a new entry, name it as you want, and copy/paste the following command:

syndaemon -k -i 2 -d &

Only drawback is that sometimes, I don't know why, I have to manually put the command in a terminal, like it hadn't work while the desktop was loading... If someone can help about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: Go to Settings > Select Trackpad > Deselect "Tap to Click".  This allows you to accidentally tap the trackpad without giving it a command. You will have to double tap to intentionally select.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mouse and Touchpad settings there should be an option under Touchpad to disable touchpad while typing.